# When using MSAL to implement AAD authentication, what would I use the navigateToLoginRequestUrl option for?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-initializing-client-applications#configuration-options) tells me what effect setting/not setting this option does, but it doesn't say *why* one would choose to set it or not set it.

When would I want to turn off/on "default navigation" to "start page" after login?  I see that if I don't set it, it defaults to true, causing my page to be loaded three times as part of a successful loginRedirect workflow (once by me, twice as redirects from the auth pages/code), but if I set it to false, my page only gets loaded twice (once by me and once as part of the redirect) and the user still appears to be logged in successfully.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an article on avoiding wildcard reply URLs with MSAL.js: https://joonasw.net/view/avoiding-wildcard-reply-urls-with-msal-js.

Here I set it to false, so that MSAL.js does not try to redirect the user back to their current page when triggering login. 
That would require the use of a wildcard reply URL in AAD. 
Setting it to false + specifying my own reply URL and implementing the handling there allows it to use one reply URL. 
And the user still gets to the page they were trying to access.

Multiple redirects should not occur. 
MSAL.js can get tokens silently after initial authentication usually.
Though I suppose the app is loaded even in the silent case since it is opened in an iframe. 
Typically you'll want to detect this situation and not load your app in the iframe.

Comment: Thank you for the article link. I see how setting this option is helpful in the situation you wrote about. In my situation I don't have multiple authenticated entrypoints, it's always just the main app URL, so it seems like there's no need for wildcard reply URLs or a centralized login-redirect handler. So, I guess it doesn't matter to what I set the option. FWIW multiple redirects do occur on initial login depending on the value of this option as I mentioned -- and it's not the frame case.  I guess that will just remain a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

As [per source](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/src/UserAgentApplication.ts), seems that determines whether after receiving the token, MSAL should navigate to your app login url.

Comment: Thank you for those details. However, I'm not looking to better understand what it does (the documentation I linked to originally indicates that as well as the source) but why one would choose to set or not set the option. When I tried adjusting it in my app, it seemed the only effect was whether or not msal redirected to my app twice instead of three times -- in both cases, the user was successfully logged in.  So what would I be missing if I set it to "false" instead of the default true value?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I **suspect** you can set it to false when developing web parts, which do not have own login UI at all.